# Jomsocial component outside joomla

Tags: iframe, joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla-component

I have a jomsocial installation at http://social.drishtant.com/social-network-for-social-impact

How can I embed the jomsocial component alone (exclude the joomla header and footer) in a third party website ? An iframe with the above mentioned URL fetches the joomla header and footer as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your Rockettheme template, you could use these steps...its a few steps, but I think it will accomplish what you want.

In short, you're going to create another main menu for use in your iframe, which you can then display differently with template configuration or template assignment.:

1. Create a new "hidden" menu that is an alias of your link to jomsocial, but don't publish the menu anywhere - it just has to exist and be published so that the itemid is valid and your jomsocial component can be reached with it.
2. From Admin, copy or create another new menu and call it something like "mainmenu_4iframe"
3. On that menu, add all the menu options that you want available from the iframe as menu *aliases*.  This then runs those menu items, but with a different menu Itemid (this is critical)
4. From your template configuration, make Menu Settings overrides for the Hidden menu item and the mainmenu_4iframe to make your template appear differently if they go to jomSocal from that link (which is the one they would use in the iframe SRC attribute)
5. If changing the default template for the menu items doesn't work or is too much trouble, you could instead, have a basic template like 'beez' or something and assign that template to your new menu items.

I think that covers it, it's been awhile since I've done it, but I think anything I've overlooked can be quickly figured out. - Good Luck

Answer (score 1):

You can exclude all the "CMS" stuff, and display only the component by adding this to the end of the url

```
&tmpl=component
```

Comment: that works fine, but is not persistent. I mean clicking on a link in the component gets back the header and footer. Is there a way I can create a different view ?

Comment: Couple of things: First, check this discussion on the topic: http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=500&t=355708

Comment: Another approach might be to use template assignment somehow.  I don't know which you use, but Gantry based templates let you configure when/which features of the template are used, or you can use another template altogether.  Then clone the menu items you're including (Alias menu items), and only display that menu on the new menu used in the iframe.  And finally, assign the different (simpler) template to those menu items that are only used on the iframe page.